# Android TimePickerDialog Android 4.4 button wrong color

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, material-components-android

I use app theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` in my application,
when i create TimePickerDialog it looks ok on Android 5 and higher, but on Android 4.4 with Holo style it looks weird:

```
return new TimePickerDialog(
        getActivity(),
        listener,
        loadAutoUpdateHour(),
        loadAutoUpdateMinute(),
        _24hourView);
```

[image]

But i want it look like this

[image]

Seems to me what MaterialComponent replace default Button to MaterialButton, but why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Material components library to 1.3.0 version, problem disappeared